# asyncio.Event is not set from signal handler

Tags: python

```py
import signal
import asyncio
from typing import Optional
from types import FrameType


async def main() -> None:
    server = (
        await asyncio.start_server(
            lambda reader, writer: None,
            '127.0.0.1',
            7070
        )
    )
    tasks = (
        asyncio.create_task(server.serve_forever()),
        asyncio.create_task(event.wait())
    )

    async with server:
        await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

    # Some shutdown logic goes here.


def handle_signal(signal: int, frame: Optional[FrameType]) -> None:
    event.set()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    event = asyncio.Event()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_signal)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I want to gracefully terminate an asyncio server if user sends SIGINT (or, in other words, presses CTRL+C).

For this reason, `asyncio.Event` is used: I use `asyncio.wait` in the main coroutine to wait till either the server has been stopped or SIGINT has been received. Signal handler has been set accordingly.

The problem is, the solution does not work (tested on Alpine Linux). Can somebody explain why exactly? Can I workaround it somehow?

Answer (score 3):

From the low-level point of view an interrupt can happen at any time between two CPU instructions and there are only few simple system calls that are safe to call in a signal handler, beacause buffers or internal data may be in an inconsistent state. The recommendation is to take a minimal action - if possible only to set a flag that is periodically checked in the program's main loop. The running program is the Python interpreter and it does exactly that.

The result is that from the programmer's point of view the signal handler call (now a Python code) can happen any time between two Python bytecode instructions. But again, the Python program's data may be in an inconsistent state and the recommendation si to take a minimal action - if possible only to set a flag ....

In addition to that, in asyncio we should treat the interrupt *like* something happening in another thread. Technically it is in the same thread, but the point is the activity in the signal handler is not controlled by the event loop, so it is like "happening elsewhere" and any changes may remain unnoticed for some time until the event loop wokes up for another reason.

Asyncio is not threadsafe, but there are few helpers. `call_soon_threadsafe` schedules a callback to be called asap (like `call_soon`), but in addition it wakes up the event loop.

```
def handle_signal(signal: int, frame: Optional[FrameType]) -> None:
    asyncio.get_running_loop().call_soon_threadsafe(evset)

def evset():
    event.set()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? It is still not clear to me why I should use ```call_soon_threadsafe``` even if signal is handled within the main thread.

Comment: The event loop will not notice the activity in the signal handler. The loop is based on a `select` (or very similar `poll`) call which monitors I/O channels with a timeout till the nearest scheduled callback. The signal will not wake up the `select`. Make a test: run the program, press ctrl-C (nothing will happen), then from another terminal connect to the server (127.0.0.1 port 7070). The network socket will change it's status, the `select` will return from sleep to handle I/O on that socket and the event loop will make an iteration - only then it will notice the change on the `event`.

Comment: Note: "The signal will not wake up the select" is a simplification, because interrupted calls are restarted. Continuation: `call_soon_threadsafe` will insert the callback to the queue of scheduled callbacks (sorted by scheduled time) and wake up the `select` (this is the key point. Try with regular `call_soon` and it will not work). The event loop will discover the freshly inserted callback to `evset` and execute it.

Comment: Is it safe to call `asyncio.get_running_loop()` in a signal handler?

Comment: @user0 - I have edited my answer it probably lacked some clarity. The problem of signal-unsafe calls exists mainly at the low-level. Getting information in a signal handler should not be a problem. Modifying data is where attention must by paid.